# Find series which of generating function is $A(z) = z^{3} A(z) +1 $ and equation for n'th element of series.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

Find series which of generating function is $A(z) = z^{3} A(z) +1 $ and equation for n'th element of series.

I wanted to check wether my solution is right . Series for z^3 is (0,0,0,1,0,...) and series for z^3 + 1 is (1,0,0,1,0,0,...) so equation for n'th element of series is $a_{n} = [n=0] + [n=3]$ is that correct?

Comment: Isn't $A(z)=1/(1-z^3)$ when you solve for $A(z)$?

Comment: Why would that be the function?

Comment: It's just algebra. You have an $A(z)$ appearing on both sides of your equation.

Comment: My friend told me this but I don't get it, where's the equation there when $A(z) +1 $ is not an equation?

Comment: $$A(z)=z^3A(z)+1$$ $$A(z)-z^3A(z)=1$$ $$(1-z^3)A(z)=1$$ $$A(z)=1/(1-z^3)$$

Comment: I didn't quite understand your objection, but remember an equation must involve an $=$, and you have to do the same thing to both sides of the equation to maintain that equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put 
$$A(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n.$$
Then you have
$$A(z) = 1 + z^3A(z),$$
so 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n = 1 + \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^{n+3}.$$
Equating the terms in the two power series gives
$a_0 = 1$, $a_1 = a_2 = 0$.  After that, you see $a_n = a_{n-3}$ for
$n\ge 3$.  This yields $a_{3n} = 1$ for all $n$ and the rest of the coefficients are zero.

Sub everthing in and watch it work.